# Selecting multiple results using AVG

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, average

So I'm trying to select multiple results from my table. I have name's for users and a score for them. User's are split into groups.

Fields necessary: groupnumber, score

I'm attempting to find the total, average, minimum and maximum scores for each group using the following:

```
SELECT groupnumber, SUM(score), AVG(score), MIN(score), MAX(score) FROM players;
```

This isn't working unfortunately. It only displays the result for my first field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT groupnumber, SUM(score), AVG(score), MIN(score), MAX(score) 
FROM players
GROUP BY groupnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT groupnumber, SUM(score), AVG(score), MIN(score), MAX(score) 
FROM players 
GROUP BY groupnumber
```